# Facebook app: How to test unapproved features

Tags: facebook

Hi I try to make the "publish_actions" feature of my web app approved but I cannot get it approved cause facebook approval system keeps asking me to include screenshot of working features.

However, I cannot provide such screenshot because the "publish_actions" feature is not approved yet.

How is it called? A catch 22 or an Chicken-Egg-dilema? Anyways...

Where should I start?
(I already tried with a test user and a developper account, both in live or developper mode)

Thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: Your app can always ask any user that have a role on the app for any permission (even if it isn't approved).

Comment: Can you provide me with more details, I can't figure out how: Is it facebook side or client side (actually it's serverside but...)?

I'm using facebook php api (not v4) because my server is not using PHP 5.4

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create test users, or add users as "Testers" or above in your App's "Roles" tab in the developer area of Facebook.

If your app is interacting with a test user or any user with an assigned role in your app, it may request permissions that have not been granted yet by Facebook for public use. There's no trick or workaround; just simply request the permissions like you normally would for any other user.